# How to Cut and Paste from Mac to Windows in Windows Remote Desktop RDC

Tags: copy-paste, remote-desktop

When using Microsoft Remote Desktop on Mac, `Command+V` doe not work to paste into the RDP session. On Mac, I use `Command+C` to copy the password, but when I switch over to the RDP session and click `Command+V`, nothing happens.

My questions is, how do I cut/copy and paste from Mac to Windows using Mac keyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I use command+C to copy the password, but when I switch over to the
>   RDC session and click command+V, nothing happens.

1. Use command+C to copy on the mac
2. Switch over to the RDP session
3. Use **control**+V to paste in the RDP session using your mac keyboard

Try testing it out using TextExit on the Mac to paste to Notepad on Windows. As where you'r trying to paste the Password may have restrictions/issues.

If you are still having issues.

Select the RDP from the main menu (close current session)

1. Click 'Edit'
2. Click 'Session'
3. Check that 'Limit copy and paste to remote session' is **Unticked**.
4. Reconnect session and test again.

Comment: For RDP v10, a new option is available under preferences as 'Use Mac shortcuts for Cut, Copy, and Paste'

Answer (score 3):

You cannot copy/paste the password on the login screen. To go around this, you can set both the user name and password in the options.
Select the RDP from the main menu (close current session)
1. Click 'Edit'
2. Click 'General'
3. Add user name and password under Credentials
4. Close and start your RDP session, it should login automatically

Comment: Works great. Saved me 2 mins per connection (which is a lot).

Answer (score 2):

With **Microsoft Remote Desktop 10** app I have noticed that to paste something to a PowerShell window I had to perform sort of a "double paste":

1. hit `Command+V` keys
2. in the PowerShell window's context menu (top left window corner, the app icon) click `Edit -> Paste` (This option is not active until you do step 1.)

Comment: Works the same for the Linux subsystems bash shell as Greg Dubicki says : double paste

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got transfer via clipboard to work.

The year is 2021, and I have Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 10.6.3 running on a Mac OS X Catalina OS X 10.15.7.  The PC I am connecting to is a Windows Server 2008 R2 DataCenter copyright 2009.

To get cut-and-paste to allow transferring clipboard data between the Mac and the PC, I did the following:

- Have "Remote Desktop" running on the Mac, but do NOT have the session connected to the PC.
- In the "Remote Desktop" app, in the "Remote Desktop" window, where there is a choice at the top of the window between "PC" versus "Workspaces", I have "PCs" selected.
- In that window, select the particular icon for the PC of concern.  In my case, I have only a single connection configured, so there is just one icon, so I just made sure that this icon is selected.
- In the application menu bar, which is always at the top of the screen on a Mac, select the "Connections" menu.
- The drop down for the "Connections" menu should present a choice labeled "Edit PC".  (If you don't see the "Edit PC" choice, then you did not correctly select the PC icon, as per prior step above.). From the "Connections" menu, select "Edit PC."
- A pop-up for "Edit PC" is displayed.
- In the "Edit PC" pop-up, there is a set of tabs "*General | Display | Devices & Audio | Folders*".  Select the tab "*Devices & Audio*".
- Within the "*Devices & Audio*" tab, there is a set of checkboxes "Printers", "Smart cards", "Clipboard".  Make sure that "Clipboard" is checked.
- In the "Edit PC" pop-up, after assuring that "Clipboard" is checked, click on "Save".

Once I did that, I was able to reconnect, and this time the Mac clipboard and the PC clipboard became unified as a single, shared clipboard.  I am now able to transfer data from Mac to PC and from PC to Mac using the clipboard; so "copy, cut, paste" all work smoothly between the machines.

Regarding meta-keys, other answers on this page explain that by default "**Command**-C" etc are used on the Mac while "**Control**-C" etc are used on Windows, and that this can be expanded so that the Mac's "Command-C" type keyboard controls will also work on the PC.  (So, at that point, both "Command" and "Control" meta keys work on the remotely connected PC).

In summary, for my problem, to get the Mac and PC clipboards to work in unison, I needed to understand that the adjustment was under "Connections", that the "Edit PC" option only shows up under certain conditions, and that the settings for the clipboard is under "Devices & Audio".

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work for "Workspaces"

Answer (score 0):

I've had perennial problems like this too. I find that sometimes a Command-C correctly "gets" the clipboard, but in Windows CTRL-V pastes nothing, as does Edit->Paste (or right click->Paste).

A simple solution sometimes works - just close the RDP window (click the red dot), and then re-login. Your work will be exactly as you left it, but (usually) cut and paste is magically fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Use `command+C` to copy the text, but do not use `command+V` as you normally do in Mac OS. Instead, use `control+V` to paste into a session in Remote Desktop.

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to paste, BUT, in the power shell, if you right click, it pastes! You can then copy it from there.